# Send data from application to IBM Bluemix http javascript adapter

Tags: ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm actually using IBM Bluemix http JavaScript adapter to post data to a cloudant database. In adapters I'm basically giving path of my 'API Connect' sevice post api through which I want to post and update my JSON data into cloudant data from my application via adapter to cloudant database.
But I'm not able to figure out on how I will be able to send the data which I'm able to get in application to http JavaScript post adapter. I have tried several ways for that but none of them worked.
Below i am providing you an image through which you can understand what i have done to send my data to adapter at runtime.
The image will be in 3 parts:-

[image: Here is the code for adapters]

[image: This is the consecutive code of first image in which i am basically doing the main thing by adding data in parametes using req.setQueryParameter. And data where i am getting is the 'adata' object which has been passed in sendRequest function as a parameter.]

[image: Last image is of adapter from where i am calling api connect service to ultimately send data in cloudant database.]

[image: In my fourth image you can actually see that i am getting an object known as data in adata and in data i am getting list of data which i need. So, what can i basically implement in my code so that i could able to send this data to my adapters and recieve in adapters and ultimately send this data to cloudant db.]

Comment: Why dont't post some of the code you have tried already?

Comment: ok i am editing this question and sending you the image.

Comment: Vivin please review my editing code so that you could get a detailed description.

Comment: The issue is still not very clear. Are your calls not reaching the server? Or is it reaching the server and you are not able to invoke the backend?

Comment: i think my calls are not reaching the server.

Comment: Try using formparams. Also, debug the network flow with Wireshark at your client side. You could also print the output in the failure callback cases, in case the server is giving an error message

Comment: Then what will i give instead of  value1 and value2. can you please tell me that ?

Comment: You will provide the values you wish to send to server - pmiwdc and abc from your example code

Answer (score 0):

To send data from client to MFP adapter in a POST request, you should use form parameters.

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/JavaAdapter/users",WLResourceRequest.POST);
var formParams = {"params":"['value1', 'value2']"};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams);
```

For more details refer to the documentation :

1) [Resource request from JavaScript (Cordova, Web) applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/)
2) [WLResourceRequest](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/wl-client-js-apidoc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html)